# Power Pivots / DAX

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I am looking to do the following with the help of DAX in a power pivot. I would like for the contribution of each security on each date to be multiplied by the product of the of the contribution factors up until the previous date (i.e. running product of contribution factors from the start date to the end date minus one day).

The results we get from the multiplication should then be aggregated across the selected date range. The desired result should be shown in only 1 column. Please see the following. Assume our date range is Jan 1 to Jan 3: Factor of cumulative return on Jan 1 = 1.029 Factor of cumulative return on Jan 2 = (1+0.029) x (1+0.018)= 1.0475

- Jan1 Security A = 0.60% Security B = 2.40% Security C = -0.10%
- Jan2 Security A = 0.60% x 1.029 Security B = -0.80% x 1.029 Security C = 2.00% x 1.029
- Jan3 Security A = -2.50% x 1.0475 Security B = -3.25% x 1.0475 Security C = 0.60% x 1.0475

The only thing that is not being scaled are the contributions for the first day in the date range. Then the scaled contributions are all added across the date range. I know this is much easier done in SQL but your help would be greatly appreciated as I'm still learning DAX.

In Power Query, I tried creating a portfolio contribution table in which I did a group by and sum on the security contributions to get the total contributions on each day, and added 1. Then created an index column and calculated the running product in M. After I created another column where I added 1 to the date to bring it forward.

Finally, I joined this table to the original by the new date (date + 1) so I can have everything on the same dates. Unfortunately, power query does not dynamically update when querying the date range in the power pivot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy4SQ.png)